# Android. Intent. ACTION_GET_CONTENT . Фильтр по типу файла

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

Добрый день
Хочу получить файл через ACTION_GET_CONTENT :

```
       (Kotlin)
        public fun onFindFile(view: View) {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            intent.type = "application/*"
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            startActivityForResult(intent, FIND_FILE)
        }
```

Вопрос. Как можно отфильтровать выбор определенного расширения?
Например у моего файла расширение *.prj (внутри текст в json формате)

Есть ли возможность запрещать выбор других типов файлов?

Answer (score 0):

Нет такой возможности.

В системе Андроид расширение не имеет значения, имеет значение MIME тип, который задаете здесь:

```
intent.type = "application/*"
```

Только так можно фильтровать контент в диалоге для выбора файлов.